# Rendering Highcharts graph

Tags: highcharts

Using Option #1 from http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation I've put together the following, but can't get the plot to render (I "run" the file in Cloud9, which starts apache that serves the page). I load the libraries and the graph script in the header, then call the graph container in the body. The code is validated by http://validator.w3.org/:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>

<html>

<head>

    <title>TheTitle</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        src = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" >
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        src = "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" >
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? You don't seem to have Jquery included -- `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No error in the C9 console, probably because I've got a setting wrong. I can get the plot to render using jsfiddle, but can't get the whole picture to work outside of it.

Comment: Because jsfiddle already has Jquery. You have to include the script I posted above in the head of your page even above `highcharts.js` and `exporting.js`.

Comment: It's there. By now I think I'm doing something wrong with C9, not the code itself. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a C9 setting: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp renders fine.

Comment: By the way there shouldn't be any error in the C9 console. I meant the browser console, if you are not using some browser in C9. Run your page in a browser like chrome and press Ctrl+Shift+j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your external script adding module with following

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Check the fiddle link for more details, http://jsfiddle.net/nzap5mc9/

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it, you add a line to load Jquery and leave both `highcharts` lines loading the Highcharts files, all three lines in the header. Do you leave the charting code in the header or in the body? I've tried both and I still can't see the graph. I've also added `/show` to the fiddle link to get a glimpse of the html, but the result is more confusing that enlightening at this stage.

Comment: Those who down vote the answer, please explain the reason so that i can update the answer.